# codeigniter: object not found

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter

I don't know what I have missed. I am just starting again in codeigniter. I don't know what will I do next. I already fix the base_url = localhost_cpu and my main folder is Cpu. do any of you know how to fix my codes. everytime I click the submit button it will say object not found.

**.htacess**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

*config*

**config.php**

```
    <?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');


$config['base_url'] =  'http://localhost/Cpu';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
$config['url_suffix'] = '';
$config['language'] = 'english';
$config['charset'] = 'UTF-8';
$config['enable_hooks'] = FALSE;
$config['subclass_prefix'] = 'MY_';
$config['composer_autoload'] = FALSE;
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-';
$config['enable_query_strings'] = FALSE;
$config['controller_trigger'] = 'c';
$config['function_trigger'] = 'm';
$config['directory_trigger'] = 'd';
$config['allow_get_array'] = TRUE;
$config['log_threshold'] = 0;
$config['log_path'] = '';
$config['log_file_extension'] = '';
$config['log_file_permissions'] = 0644;
$config['log_date_format'] = 'Y-m-d H:i:s';
$config['error_views_path'] = '';
$config['cache_path'] = '';
$config['cache_query_string'] = FALSE;
$config['encryption_key'] = '';
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = NULL;
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
$config['cookie_prefix']    = '';
$config['cookie_domain']    = '';
$config['cookie_path']      = '/';
$config['cookie_secure']    = FALSE;
$config['cookie_httponly']  = FALSE;
$config['standardize_newlines'] = FALSE;
$config['global_xss_filtering'] = FALSE;
$config['csrf_protection'] = FALSE;
$config['csrf_token_name'] = 'csrf_test_name';
$config['csrf_cookie_name'] = 'csrf_cookie_name';
$config['csrf_expire'] = 7200;
$config['csrf_regenerate'] = TRUE;
$config['csrf_exclude_uris'] = array();
$config['compress_output'] = FALSE;
$config['time_reference'] = 'local';
$config['rewrite_short_tags'] = FALSE;
$config['proxy_ips'] = '';
```

**routes.php**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

$route['default_controller'] = 'Scheduling';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

**autoload.php**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

$autoload['packages'] = array();
$autoload['libraries'] = array('session','database','form_validation');
$autoload['drivers'] = array();
$autoload['helper'] = array('url','form','html');
$autoload['config'] = array();
$autoload['language'] = array();
$autoload['model'] = array();
```

*model*

**Scheduling_model.php**

```
        <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class Scheduling_model extends CI_Model {

        public function __construct(){
            parent::__construct();
        }

    }

*controller*

**Scheduling.php**
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Scheduling extends CI_Controller{

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('scheduling_model');
    }

    public function index(){
        $this->first();
    }

    public function first(){
        $this->load->view('first.php');
    }

    public function priority(){
        $this->load->view('second.php');
    }
}
```

*view*

**first.php**

```
    <?php echo form_open("priority"); ?>


Enter no of process
<input type="text" name="processes" value="<?php echo set_value('processes')?>" >
<input type="submit" value="Submit">

<?php 
    echo form_close(); 
?>
```

Comment: are you sure mod_rewrite is active? you mind checking rewrite_module in httpd.conf

Comment: Just tip: on the base url in config end it with '/' like `$config['base_url'] =  'http://localhost/yourproject/';` and when loading views you don't need `.php`

Comment: You are missing controller name in form open `<?php echo form_open("scheduling/priority"); ?>`

Comment: On routes.php change `$route['default_controller'] = 'Scheduling';` to `$route['default_controller'] = 'scheduling';` lower case in routes.php check file like `application/controllers/Scheduling.php`

Comment: Also this may help https://github.com/wolfgang1983/htaccess_for_codeigniter